# Determine the changelist used to submit new changes in perforce

Tags: version-control, perforce, changelist

A workspace is synced to a particular changelist `A`. User makes changes in the workspace and submits the changes which shows up as changelist `B`. Is there a way to figure out `A` given `B`?

Answer (score 2):

Files must be synced to the head revision before they can be modified, so as far as the files in `B` are considered, `A` = `B-1`.

There is no requirement that all of the files in a workspace be synced to the same changelist, or that they be synced at all, and there is no way to determine given `B` what revision **other** files were synced to at the time `B` was submitted.